# Transactions in Ruby Sequel module: how to get DB object?

Tags: ruby, sinatra, sequel

I'm working in a Sinatra application using Sequel.

I want to make a transaction, according to the [manual](http://sequel.rubyforge.org/rdoc/files/doc/transactions_rdoc.html) I have to use the DB object, how can I get this object from any part of my code?

Comment: Take a look at the top of http://sequel.rubyforge.org/rdoc/classes/Sequel.html where it just defines a constant called `DB`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can define it in your base app.rb (or equivalent) or include a separate file where you configure the DB object if you wish.

For example, in one of my Sinatra apps, I have an app.rb that includes a

```
class App < Sinatra::Application
  #lots of stuff here...
end

require_relative 'models/init'
```

In my models/init.rb I configure DB

```
require 'sequel'

conf = YAML.load(File.open(File.expand_path('./config/dbconn.yml')))
env = ENV['RACK_ENV'] || 'development'
DB = Sequel.connect(host:conf['database'][env]['host'],
                    port:conf['database'][env]['port'],
                    database:conf['database'][env]['schema'],
                    username:conf['database'][env]['username'],
                    password:conf['database'][env]['password'],
                    adapter:conf['database'][env]['adapter'],
                    encoding:conf['database'][env]['encoding'])
raise "Unable to connect to #{conf['database'][env]['host']}" unless DB.test_connection

...
```

That's one way. Hope it helps.

Comment: Thank you very much, however, this would force me to create a connection every time a request is made. Don't they have some method to retrieve the current connection the models are using?

Comment: Sequel manages it's own connection pool so there's no need to worry about that side of things.

Comment: Also, if you're worried about things getting configured more than once, just make use of Sinatra's configuration helpers. See http://www.sinatrarb.com/intro#Configuration

Comment: I can paste an example of how I configure my app.rb file if that will help you wrap your head around it. Let me know.

Answer (score 1):

You mention that you want to reference from any part of your code; however I've found that encapsulated within the models is where I tend to wrap transactions; and from there it's relatively easy:

```
class X < Sequel::Model
  def self.y
    self.db.transaction {
    ...
    end
  end
  def z
    db.transaction {
    ...
    }
  end
end
```