# How do I get the current database object in Sequel running with Rails?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, sequel

I need to get the current database object from Sequel in a Rails application. I cannot define it for various reasons, like it is advised in "[Transactions in Ruby Sequel module: how to get DB object?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13593295/transactions-in-ruby-sequel-module-how-to-get-db-object)". My database uses JDBC defined in database.yml.

I can get `Database.current`, but it seems I can't do any operation on it, like add a logger, like I can do on DB object defined for Sequel in another app:

```
lger = Logger.new(STDOUT)
DB.sql_log_level = :debug
DB.loggers << lger
```

Doing this on `Database.current` or `Database.current()` causes "no such method" exceptions, so I need to get the actual DB object used by Sequel.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It took me a while to remember how to do this, and, I'm not entirely positive it'll work with Rails, but...

When using models with Sequel, which is probably what happens with Rails, you can get at the "DB" object. I have a table called `acls`. My model is `Acl`. When I load my models I can do:

```
require 'sequel'
require 'logger'

# ... make my connection then load my models ...

# turn on logging...
Acl.db.loggers << Loggers.new(STDOUT)
Acl.first 
# => I, [2013-02-18T16:55:13.561148 #94494]  INFO -- : (0.010879s) SELECT * FROM `acls` LIMIT 1
```

And, this works too:

```
Acl.db.sql_log_level = :debug
```

Comment: (being newbie at Sequel) I have found that Sequel::Model.db also gets current db. But your post nudged me in the right direction. Thanks!!!